# 454 Error: authentication failed when using Net::SMTP::SSL to send email

Tags: perl, email, ssl

I use [`Net::SMTP::SSL`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP::SSL) to sent email in Perl, and got "454 Error: authentication failed"

Here is my code:

```
use Net::SMTP::SSL;         
$smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new($smtp2, Port => $smtp_port2, Timeout => 10, Debug => 1); 
$smtp->auth($login2, $password2);
$smtp->mail($login2); 
$smtp->to($to);    
$smtp->data();  
$smtp->datasend("To: $to\n");
$smtp->datasend("From: Aspiring error email \n");
$smtp->datasend("Date: $today\n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: $subject\n");

$smtp->datasend("\n");  
$smtp->datasend($message);  
$smtp->dataend();    
$smtp->quit;
```

And i got these message:

> `Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0xf9ab80)<<< 454 Error: authentication failed, system busy`

It seem i failed to auth, and i am sure the username and pw is correct.
Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

> 454 Error: authentication failed, system busy

These are temporary problems.
The mail server is probably not doing local verification of the password, but is using an external system like a Radius or LDAP server, and the connection to this authentication system failed. Just try again later and hope that the problem got resolved.

If the credentials were wrong the server would have send a 535 status code.
See also the status codes in [RFC4954](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954#page-11).